# filter is not working when using Microsoft Graph API to List Groups with Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Powershell, running multiple Graph API are fine.
trying to get list of groups with teams by following below Doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"
$groups = GetGraphData($uri,$headerParams)
```

the response is same like I didn't use the filter, still including all of groups which resourceProvisioningOptions is not 'Team', so it seems not working.

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups"
```

is there any mistake when above $uri string combined?  on /Any(x:x eq 'Team')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your filter expression is ignored since PowerShell tries to expand `$` into a variable. A *dollar sign* needs to be escaped, in Powershell with  "`" (backward apostrophe/grave) character:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?`$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')"
```

Alternately use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`:

```
$uri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq ''Team'')'
```